# Two tasks are firing even when there's only one item, using async/await and Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

What's wrong with my code here?  Even when items.count is only 1, the DoSomething method gets called twice, and counter is equal to 2.  Have I not structured the awaits correctly or am I using the WhenAll incorrectly?

```
public async Task<int> Process(string id)
    {
        var items = await GetItemsAsync(id);
        var counter = 0;

        var tasks = items.Select(async item =>
            {
                if (await DoSomething(item))
                    counter++
            });

            if (tasks.Count() > 0)
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        return counter;
     }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using `Select` incorrectly, basically. It's lazy, remember? So every time you iterate over it (once for `Count()` and once in `WhenAll`)... it's going to call your delegate again.

The fix is simple: just materialize the query, e.g. with `ToList()`:

```
var tasks = items.Select(async item =>
{
    if (await DoSomething(item))
    {
        counter++
    }
}).ToList();
```

That way you create the tasks *once*. In fact, `tasks.Count()` doesn't need to iterate at all now, as it's optimized to use the `Count` property. But I'd still use `Any()` instead:

```
if (tasks.Any())
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

(I'd strongly advise *always* using braces, by the way. It's much more bug-resistant...)

Comment: To be more specific, `tasks.Count()` caused an extra "unexpected" iteration

Comment: @JonSkeet Great thanks! Alternatively I could also add the tasks to a list (of tasks) using a foreach loop, right?

Comment: @Prabhu: You could, but it would be pretty longwinded compared with just calling `ToList`...